# Vue.js handling data not yet loaded

Tags: vue.js, apollo, vue-apollo

I'm trying to get my head around the best way of doing things in Vue and getting a little stuck when it comes to using data that hasn't been loaded.

I'm in the middle of creating a 'show' view for a resource which is loaded via vue-apollo, and the form consists of two components: the form component, and the 'edit' component (form is shared between new and edit).

My form looks a bit like this

```
<template lang="pug">
  form
    input(v-model='model.name')
    input(v-model='model.description')
</template>

<script>
import clone from 'ramda';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      model: clone(this.value),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

And the 'edit' component like this

```
<template lang="pug">
  resource-form(v-model='resource')
</template>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export default {
  apollo: {
    resource() {
      return gql'{
        resource(id: ${this.$route.params.id}) {
          name
          description
        }
      }';
    }
  }
  data() {
    return {
      model: clone(this.value),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

When the page loads, I get a bunch of errors about being unable to read the properties 'name' and 'description' of undefined, which makes sense given `resource` isn't set on initial page load, but what is the best way of handling this?

There has to be a cleaner way of handling it than constantly checking if `model` is null.

Comment: What about wrapping your `input` with `span(v-if="model")` so that they don't try to use the value unless `model` is not undefined?

Comment: Why not use the [ApolloQuery component](https://akryum.github.io/vue-apollo/guide/components/query.html)? The point being, this is built into the library you appear to be using. You can use ApolloQuery and scoped templates to only render the child components when you actually have data.

Comment: where is `this.value` coming from?

Comment: @zero298 that's the one option but I was hoping there was a nicer way of doing it but if not then I guess that'll have to do

Comment: @Bert That looks perfect, although I'm having an issue. Seems like binding `v-model="data.resource"` isn't working, still getting errors

Comment: @Daniel sorry I didn't show in the code but there's a prop `value` which is set using v-model

Comment: @Bert was being daft, it works just fine. But I need to get the data out of the slot for that component as well so ended up wrapping it in a v-if